# Extending XML validation / auto-completion

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I have several types of data-sources, that I would like to use for additional XML validation and providing auto-completion (using Eclipse if possible).

This source could be some other XML (from another or the same file):

```
<type name="TypeA"/>
<type name="TypeB"/>
```

or a Java-class

```
public List<String> getValues() {
    return Arrays.asList("Val1", "Val2", "Val3");
}
```

---

These values are then referenced in other XML-files:

```
<x type="TypeA" value="Val2" />
<x type="TypeB" value="Val3" />
```

Now I would like to improve editing this file by

- **Validating** the XML-File 
  (underline wrong types/values, if possible display a red x in Package Expl.)
- Providing **code-completion** 
  (suggest `TypeA` and `TypeB` when typing `type="`)

---

I'll certainly have to write some code, but what is the best way start?

- Can the standard XML-Editor be extended?
- Are there any plugins that can help? <sub>(Maybe [Rinzo XML Editor](http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/extendingRinzo.html)?)</sub>
- Any other options that I did not think of?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure eclipse already does both these things but they are part of one of the extended packages. Try downloading eclipse for Java EE developers. I'm fairly sure validation and completetion are part of the Web Tools Platform.

Check [Here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user/topics/twxvalid.html) For Validating XML

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not talking about checking for valid and well-formed XML files, but about additional checks that Eclipse cannot know about.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `XSD` schemas for your `XML` files, then `Eclipse` can validate them.

There are, for sure, frameworks who generate `XSD` schemas from your `Java` classes.

Check the answers here: [utility to generate xsd from java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681373/utility-to-generate-xsd-from-java-class)

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting idea! If possible I'd like to avoid re-generating my xsd whenever the source files change, though.

Comment: I know http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaxb-builder/ for the other-way generation Java->XSD

Comment: @PeterLang If you found a framework that uses `Maven`, you can let the generation happens during `Maven` build, but this will not help you for code-completion

Answer (score 0):

If you decide extending Rinzo, it seems documentation has bee updated on how to extend the same features you'll like to customize :)

http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/extendingRinzo.html

Comment: Thanks, I've already seen that. Do you have any experience using Rinzo?

Answer (score 0):

Peter,

I answer you in a new post since I didn't have enough space in a comment.

If you want to extend Rinzo according to your example I guess you'll need to create a plugin contributing the extension points declared in the site's documentation.

For the content assistant implementation I guess a rough implementation based on your examples could be as follow:

```java
public class CustomSourceAssistProcessor implements IXMLContentAssistProcessor {
@Override
public void addAttributeValuesProposals(XMLNode currentNode, String attributeName, String prefix,
        ITextViewer viewer, int offset, Collection<ICompletionProposal> results) {
    if("x".equals(currentNode.getTagName()) && "type".equals(attributeName)) {
        for (String possibleValue : this.getPossibleValuesFromXML()) {
            results.add(new CompletionProposal(possibleValue, offset, prefix.length(), 0, null, "Proposal Description...", null, null));
        }
    }
    if("x".equals(currentNode.getTagName()) && "value".equals(attributeName)) {
        for (String possibleValue : this.getPossibleValuesFromJavaClass()) {
            results.add(new CompletionProposal(possibleValue, offset, prefix.length(), 0, null, "Proposal Description...", null, null));
        }
    }
}
```

}

That's as far as interacting with Rinzo's API, and your particular logic to gather values either from an external XML file or java-class should be implemented in the methods **getPossibleValuesFromXML()** and **getPossibleValuesFromJavaClass()**

On the other hand in order to add your custom validator I guess the rough implementation of your extension point, also based on your example, should be similar to this one:

```java
public class CustomSourceXMLValidator implements XmlValidator {
@Override
public void validate(RinzoXMLEditor editor) {
    editor.getModel().getTree().accept(new HierarchicalVisitor() {
        @Override
        public boolean visitStart(XMLNode node) {
            if(node.isTag() && "x".equals(node.getTagName())) {
                for (Entry<String, XMLAttribute> entry : node.getAttributes().entrySet()) {
                    if("type".equals(entry.getKey())) {
                        this.validateValueFromXML(entry.getValue().getValue());
                    }
                    if("value".equals(entry.getKey())) {
                        this.valdateValueFromJavaClass(entry.getValue().getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        private void valdateValueFromJavaClass(XMLAttribute xmlAttribute) {
            if(!this.getPossibleValuesFromXML().contains(xmlAttribute.getValue())) {
                this.createMarker(editor, xmlAttribute);
            }
        }
        private void validateValueFromXML(XMLAttribute xmlAttribute) {
            if(!this.getPossibleValuesFromJavaClass().contains(xmlAttribute.getValue())) {
                this.createMarker(editor, xmlAttribute);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

And once again it's up to you the implementation of the methods **getPossibleValuesFromXML()** and **getPossibleValuesFromJavaClass()**.
You can also see the source code of **ClassNamesValidatorVisitor** as an example.

Keep on rockin' in the free world! :)

Comment: I just wanted to know if you have experience, but thanks for the samples! ;-) Have you used Rinzo? BWT: Instead of adding a new answer, the StackOverflow-way would have been to edit your existing answer.